# IE7 failing to remove an element according to it's href attribute

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

Ah, is it ever really over if there's still an IE?

Thanks to the invaluable help of Stack Overflowers, I have my jQuery working perfectly in FF, Safari, Chrome & Oprah. Naturally, it fails in IE7, which evidently has trouble href attributes, e.g.:

```
$('li a[href="' + title + '"]').parent().remove();
```

Can someone shed some light on an alternative syntax that IE7 will understand to remove the un-checked item from the list? Many thanks in advance!

Here's the works:

```
<div class="product-module">
<div class="product-pic">
    <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
        <label for="compare1">
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="compare" id="compare1" />
            Compare
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-info">
    <p><a href="#" title="#"><span class="product-name">Product Name here</span></a></p>    
</div>
```

```
<div class="compare">
<ul>
</ul>
<p class="compare-button"><button type="submit">Compare</button></p>
<p class="clear-selections"><a class="button" id="clear-selections" href="#">Clear Selections</a></p>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// clear all checkboxes on load
$(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
});


$(function(){
    $('.column-main input[type="checkbox"]').click(function()    {
        var title = $(this).closest('.product-module').find('.product-name').html();

        // if user checks the checkbox, add the item to the ul
        if    ($(this).attr('checked'))    {
        var html = '<li><a href="'+title+'">' + title + '</a></li>';
        $('.compare ul').append(html);

        // un-checking the checkbox removes the corresponding item from the ul
        }    else {
        // $('.compare li a').attr('href', title).parent().remove();
        $('li a[href="' + title + '"]').parent().remove();        //    works in real browsers; fails in IE7
        }
    })
});



    $(function(){
    $('.clear-selections').click(function(){
        $('.compare ul').empty();
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', false);
    })
});


$(function(){
    $('.compare button').click(function(){
        minRequests = 2;
        maxRequests = 3;
        requested = $('.compare ul li').size();    // go figure: why not .length()?

        if(requested < 2)    {
        alert ('Compare ' + requested + ' products?');

        } else if((requested >= 2) && (requested <= 5 ))    {
        alert ('There are ' + requested + ' products to compare');

        } else {
        alert (requested + ' is too many');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you compare the `title` to the `href` of the element? I believe in IE it uses the absolute url instead of relative, so you may want to double check the `href` value before assuming something will work.

You may be able to use `[href*=` instead of `href=`

**Never assume**, always check. Do alerts on the `attr('href')` and make sure they match.

Comment: Thanks meder. Hacking at this all week has been exhausting but I do have a working solution, I will try to post when I'm rested so others can see the solution